# Is this a thread safe way to handle blocking close?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

A thread opens a resource, which is a blocking operation. If and once it succeeded, the thread is required to close it again, which again is blocking but always succeeds in finite time.

It is possible to use a flag (let's call it `hasResource`), which cannot be synchronized with other threads in any way, to indicate that the thread does not want to be interrupted. No other synchronization is allowed at all.

Is the following a safe way to handle this scenario?

```
@Override // we're subclassing Thread
public void run () {
    try {
        while (!interrupted ()) {
            blockingOpen ();
            // glitch possibility in this line
            hasResource = true;
            blockingClose ();
            hasResource = false;
        }
    }
    catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        interrupt ();
    }
}
```

In particular, does this ensure that the thread will no be interrupted while it has the resource?

As far as I can tell, there is only one window of error opportunity, which is right after the Open and before setting the flag. However, it seems this would not lead to leaking the resource, but to accidentally ignoring the interrupt request. Is it possible to prevent that?

Comment: Actually, regarding my final paragraph, does Thread.sleep() throw an IE if the thread already was interrupted when the sleep began? That would change things. The javadoc does not clearly state either way.

Comment: Added as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710025

Comment: Have you tried to interrupt during sleep after interrupt? I would imagine that this behaviour is more easily tested and would help get an answer to the original question.

Comment: Doing that right now :)

Comment: Interestingly, attempting to sleep throws if the interrupted flat was set earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The original code is in fact correct. Setting the bool flag is not a problem, even though the question mistakenly suggests it could be. There are two points to be considered for this to be clear:

Firstly, the line itself cannot cause an error. If the Open succeeded, the flag *will* be set - always. Not even a StackOverflow or OutOfMemory can reasonably occur here.

Secondly, if `interrupt()` is called while no interruptible code (e.g. a sleep) is executed, then the `interrupted` flag will be set. The next time any interruptible code begins execution, this flag will be checked, and instead of running the code, an Interrupted exception will be thrown.

Thus, the original code works indeed as intended.

Comment: Ah, now I see what your issue was back then. This still leaves unsolved the matter of closing the resource, but I suppose, that the original question does not really require it.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to use a flag (let's call it hasResource), which cannot be synchronized with other threads in any way, to indicate that the thread does not want to be interrupted. No other synchronization is allowed at all.

No it isn't.

> does this ensure that the thread will no be interrupted while it has the resource?

No. *If* `hasResource` is `volatile` *and* all your other threads know about `hasResource` *and* observe it, then you've inhibited yourself from calling `Thread.interrupt()`, but you haven't inhibited *Java* from doing so.

Why your application threads would be interrupting each other is another question. Never used this feature in 20 years.

Comment: Actually, in this specific case `Thread.interrupt()` can be inhibited — since @mafu overrides the Thread, he can also override `Thread.interrupt()` to check the flag and ignore the interrupt when necessary. Btw, "Never used this feature in 20 years", — have you never used an Executor or Future? Most threading frameworks in Java make use of Thread interruption to cancel tasks. It might not be popular with server programmers, but when desktop/mobile programmers ignore it, we end up with wonders like uninterruptible hanged downloads or compilation tasks, that can not be stopped for hours.